# Application Insights REST API difference between 'get' and 'execute'

Tags: azure, rest, azure-application-insights

I want to query data from Azure Application Insights. In [Azure REST Api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query), they have two operations:

1. execute
2. get

The problem is that they both "Execute an Analytics query". What's the difference between them and what should one use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that to execute a query you need to do a POST with the query details in the body whereas getting a query result you need a GET with the query details in the url parameters.

Which one to use is a matter of preference. If you don't want executed queries in your logs you might prefer the POST since the query text is not a url parameter.